# Find elements in cell array (logical 0 or 1)

Tags: matlab, boolean, cell

I have a cell column vector of stock symbols that are all three letters long. I need to create a column vector of the same length that returns a 1 when the symbol XYZ is present, and 0 when it is not. I have wasted 2+ hours trying to figure this out, it is very frustrating.

For example, if I have this:

```
XYZ
DHU
EYU
XYZ
XYZ
```

then I need a column vector like this:

```
1
0
0
1
1
```

I appreciate the help. Have a great weekend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use [strcmp](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html)

```
s1 = 'XYX';
s2 = {'XYZ';'DHU';'EYU';'XYZ';'XYZ'};

tf = strcmp(s1,s2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since all cells consist of three letters, you can convert them to character array with [`char()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/char.html) and then use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) for comparisons, like so -

```
>> A = {'XYZ';'DHU';'EYU';'XYZ';'XYZ'};
>> all(bsxfun(@eq,char(A),'XYZ'),2)
ans =
     1
     0
     0
     1
     1
```